# Entity Framework 5 DbContext and Connections

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

Does Entity Framework create new a connection to the database on creating a new instance of `DbContext` ?

Comment: This may helps.. [DbContext](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the DavidG, **No** it's doesn't create a connection at that point.

**Connection are only persisted when SaveChanges() is called**

Any changes made to your `entities`, be it `updates, inserts or deletes`, are only persisted to the database when the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method is called. If a `DbContext` instance is disposed before its `SaveChanges()` method was called, none of the `inserts, updates or deletes` done through this `DbContext` will be persisted to the data store.

Comment: Would be great..!!

Comment: Hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

So take this code as an example:

```
var context = new MyContext();
var cars = context.Cars.Where(c => c.TopSpeed > 100);
var carList = cars.ToList(); //Connection will probably happen here
```

Where is a connection initiated? There's actually 2 possibilities. Generally there will only ever be a connection created on the last line. Instantiating a context doesn't have any side effects and the middle line is using deferred execution so doesn't need a connection yet.

However, you may find that the second line will cause a connection to be created, this will happen when your app spins up for the first time and Entity Framework needs to go and confirm that your database matches what it thinks it should be. You can disable this by disabling the initialiser, for example:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

How about writing to the database? Well, you have something similar going on, but this time the only time a connection is needed is when you call `SaveChanges`:

```
var context = new MyContext();
var ferarri = new Car { Name = "Ferarri", TopSpeed = 170 };
context.Cars.Add(ferarri);
context.SaveChanges(); //Connection will probably happen here
```

Is that all? Well no, you will also get a new connection when you start a transaction:

```
//Database connection will be opened here
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var cars = context.Cars.Where(c => c.TopSpeed > 100);
    var carList = cars.ToList();        
}
```